# Theorem: every bounded sequence with an unique limit is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why exactly does a sequence need to be bounded to be convergent?  I mean if a sequence has a limit its convergent, why do we need to state that it is bounded, is this theorem faulty or am I missing something?

Comment: You must be leaving something out  - the result you state is just silly, since if a sequence has a limit then it's convergent by definition. Perhaps it was really "every bounded sequence with a unique limit point is convergent"?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am saying, I think my book is faulty

Answer (score 1):

Given the language of the theorem it seems to me that in this context a limit of a sequence is the **unique** limit of a subsequence.

For example, using this definition the sequence $(x_{n})$, where for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define $x_{2n}=1$ and $x_{2n+1}=0$, has two limits, $1$ and $0$.

This way an unbounded sequence can have a limit, for example the sequence $(x_{n})$, where for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define $x_{2n}=n$ and $x_{2n+1}=0$, has limit $0$, but does not converge to $0$.

I agree the definitions the writer seems to use are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant a sequence with a unique limit point(also known as subsequential limit) and is bounded then the sequence is convergent. If that's the case then the theorem is right. Because the limit point is different from limit of a sequence.

Limit of a sequence is a $ \,\,l \in \mathbb R $ s.t. any neighbourhood around $ l $ contains all the element of a sequence after some index $n_0 \in \mathbb N$

Whereas a limit point(subsequential limit) is a $ \,\,l \in \mathbb R $ s.t. any neighbourhood around $ l $ contains infinitely many element of the sequence. (Not all)

The reason we need boundedness is because we can have non converging sequence with unique limit point as stated by Floris Claassens in their 2nd example.i.e.

Consider a sequence such that $x_{2n} = 0$ and $x_{2n} = n$, this sequence has a unique limit point which 0, but it diverges.